# How can I change the following Unity C# gameobject left/right swipe code for Mouse clicks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to test the game on Unity editor that's why I want to change the following code for mouse click as 'touch' don't work in unity editor. I have to make an APK each time to test the game. Please help me with this.

```
float swipespeed = 0.002f;
void Update 
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        // Get movement of the finger since last frame
        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
        float pos=touchDeltaPosition.x;
        // Move object across XY plane
        transform.Translate( 0f,0f,-pos * swipespeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know you already selected an answer, but please consider looking at the other answers as well for best practice information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the rest works as you need you could check [Input.mousePresent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePresent.html)

> Indicates if a mouse device is detected.
>
> On Windows, Android and Metro platforms, this function does actual mouse presence detection, so may return true or false. On Linux, Mac, WebGL, this function will always return true. On iOS and console platforms, this function will always return false.

or alternatively also [`Input.touchSupported`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touchSupported.html)

> Returns whether the device on which application is currently running supports touch input.
>
> Rather than checking the platform, use this property to determine whether your game should expect touch input, as some platforms can support multiple input methods.

and do something like

```
public float swipeSpeed = 0.002f;

// Here every frame the last mousePosition will be stored
// so we can compare the current one against it
private Vector3 lastMousePos;

private void Update 
{
    if(Input.mousePresent)
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            var currentMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            var mouseDeltaPosition = currentMousePos - lastMousePos;

            transform.Translate( 0f,0f, -mouseDeltaPosition.x * swipespeed);
        }

        // update the last position with the current
        lastMousePos = currentMousePos;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            // Get movement of the finger since last frame
            var touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

            // Move object across XY plane
            transform.Translate( 0f,0f, -touchDeltaPosition.x * swipespeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In coding, there are multiple solutions to every problem! I just wanted to invite you to take a look at Platform Dependent Compilation that Unity provides for your future projects. It removes the need for additional runtime environment checks. In this use-case, it likely won't make much of a difference, but for games that push the limits of performance it can have a huge impact.

Comment: one single bool check is not a performance impact at all. Depending on how many device targets you are going to tackle having individual platform dependent compilation can become a huge unnecessary overhead. Yes in case of `#if UNITY_EDITOR` there is only one but still you will always have to test both cases in all scripts using platform dependent code.

Comment: Your code is platform dependent and will need to be tested that way with both solutions. Like I said, there are multiple solutions to every problem. Yours is adequate and this use-case is not a noticeable difference. When your platform dependent controllers get more and more complex you end up with a much bigger memory footprint if you do not build it down to the compilation level.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than build a monolithic if/else structure that will compile into your code and be executed by all platforms, consider lookin at [Platform Dependent Compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html). This allows you to write code that compiles differently for specific environments.

For example:

```
public float swipeSpeed = 0.002f;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private Vector3 lastMousePos;
#endif

private void Update 
{
    bool touch;
    Vector3 deltaPosition;

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        touch = Input.GetMouseButton(0);
        if(touch)
        {
            deltaPosition = Input.mousePosition - lastMousePos;
            lastMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        }
    #else
        touch = (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved);
        if(touch)
        {
            deltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition
        }
    #endif


    if(touch)
    {
        transform.Translate( 0f,0f, -deltaPosition.x * swipespeed);
    }
}
```

Update: Since apparently telling someone to drop their ego gets my comment deleted, no this is not a duplicate of his/her answer. This is best practice for multi-platform development and differs significantly from his/her answer.